# Gruntjs - Running Multiple Blocking Tasks in a Specific Order ( Mongo & Node.js )

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shell, terminal, gruntjs

I've recently taken a love to Gruntjs and have been happily throwing in at every opportunity to make my development life that much easier. I currently have it compiling my SASS files, running watches, and using nodemon to keep my node server updating as I work on the app.

So here's where I've spent the morning driving myself nuts. I would like to start MongoDB prior to the Node application running. In the Node app's setup, I check for any values in the databases, and if it's empty, push a test file full of information into the tables.

I've currently tried using [grunt-concurrent](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-concurrent) and [grunt-shell-spawn](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-shell-spawn) to run the necessary mongo and node commands.

```
grunt.initConfig({
  shell: {
    mongo: {
      command: 'mongo'
    },
    node: {
      command: 'node app.js'
    }
  },
  concurrent: {
    dev: {
      tasks: ['shell:mongo','shell:node'],
      options: { logConcurrentOutput: true }
    }
  }
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell-spawn');
```

Is there a way to ensure that the mongo command reaches it's "blocking" state prior to running the node task? I'm guessing that this could be done by running the node task async on a setTimeout function, but I don't want to have to constantly be waiting to see changes in the development process take effect. Currently I have been keeping a separate shell tab open for the database and would really like to integrate this into Grunt to keep everything in one place.

I'm not sure about it's importance on a broad scale, but anyone that's utilizing Node.js and MongoDB would really find this useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Trying using grunt-nodemon with shell:mongo while specifying "options: { async: true }"

```
concurrent: {
        tasks: ['shell', 'nodemon'],
        options: {
            logConcurrentOutput: true
        }
    },
    shell: {
        mongo: {
            command: 'mongod',
            options: {
                async: true
            }
        }
    },
nodemon: {
        dev: {
            script: "server.js",
        }
    }
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Nodemon is a nice tool for managing a development setup of Node, but that really wasn't the point of this question. Do you have a test example where shell:mongo reaches it's blocking state _every time_ prior to nodemon starting up? The async option doesn't guarantee this.

Answer (score -2):

You can interval check the mongodb's service port to see if it is accessible?\

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/about, to get more understanding about questions/answers here on SO. Your contribution is not answering the question. It is more a comment, which you can add once you'll increase your reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation